# https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js generates uncaught exception: [object Object]

Tags: authentication, firefox, gmail-api

When loading https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js an uncaught exception: [object Object] is generated under Firefox (works fine in Chrome) which makes it impossible to retrieve user data after login with Gmail.

Really penalizing issue... anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with that too and found that Firefox needs to accept third-party cookies in order for Google api to load properly.

So I suggest trying to edit 'Preferences' -> 'Privacy and Security' -> 'Accept third-party cookies'. Try to set value to 'always' and see if that solves your issue. It would be more secure however to add an exception for the specific url.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved when you use https.